# Parsing string value to hex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hex, parseint

That is quite strange, isn't it? If I recall only 0-9, A, B, C, D, E, F letters represent a hexadecimal value. How come ABCDEFGHAIJ has hexadecimal representation?

[image: Parsing string to hex number in javascript.]

Comment: `parseInt("abcdefghi", 16)` breaks on the first non-hexa character it encounters. So, what you get is `0xABCDEF`

Comment: If only there was [some doco for `parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)...

Comment: Sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/y8ayx3w8/) for @Arnauld's comment

Comment: Ahahaha, I thought it is doing some conversion, something like bigger values than the range go circular from the lowest number and then does some calculation. Didn't try to check this :)

Comment: *"If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed."* - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Ok. The answer is quite basic. Delete the question? Or its useful?

Comment: @Vlad I just posted an answer to it sum it up, but I'll let you decide if it's worth it or not. (No worries at all if you delete it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) in the comments, here is the relevant part of the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to explain this behavior:

> *If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates
>   numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.*

Consequently, `parseInt("abcdefghij", 16)` will actually parse `"abcdef"` and stop there. Hence the result:

```
0xABCDEF = 11259375
```

Knowing this, you may want to use a custom function that will instead return `NaN` when invoked with a non-hexadecimal string:

```js
function parseTrueHexa(str) {
  return str.match(/^ *[a-f0-9]+ *$/i) ? parseInt(str, 16) : NaN;
}

console.log("parseInt() says:");
console.log(parseInt("aBcD", 16));
console.log(parseInt("abcdz", 16));

console.log("parseTrueHexa() says:");
console.log(parseTrueHexa("aBcD"));
console.log(parseTrueHexa("abcdz"));
```